# How to generate script to drop column using SMO with SQL Server?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, smo

I want to use SMO to generate scripts to remove some columns of a table.

In the case os Indexes I am able to generate the drop script using

```
ScriptingOptions drop = new ScriptingOptions
{
      ScriptDrops = true,
      IncludeIfNotExists = true
};                
                
Index sourceIndex = sourceTable.Indexes[originalName];
    
var script = sourceIndex.Script(drop);
```

How I can generate the script to drop a column? Object Column of SMO doesn't have a method Script().

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to use powershell as the demonstration, but I think it should be immediately transferrable.

```
$alter_opts = New-DbaScriptingOption;
$alter_opts.ScriptForAlter = $true;

$db = Get-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance . -Database myDB;
$tbl = $db.Tables['myTable'];
$tbl.Columns['ColumnToBeDropped'].MarkForDrop($true);

$tbl.Script($alter_opts);
```

The magic (if there is any) is in that `MarkForDrop($true)` call. That's telling SMO to drop the column the next time `Alter()` is called on the table.

Comment: Thanks for your help!. It generates the script correctly ! :)
I can assume that this way I will be able to change the column type as well.

Comment: It seems to work with my limited testing. Though there it's more straightforward insofar as you do something like `$col.DataType = «NewDT»` and then call `$tbl.Script($opts)`.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to create only a single column script? 
I mean from  a table of multiples columns only generate:

ALTER TABLE [Table_Test]
ADD [Column_Test] [int] NULL
GO